# Windows 7: every popup window is maximized

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I know this is a quite odd question, and I don't really know how to provide more elements to help you find a question. All I can say is that, suddenly, every window that has the chance to maximize itself will start maximized. One of the many examples is Chrome's preferences window, that should be a fairly small window but opens at full screen (1920x1080). Do someone have a clue?

Please help me in finding some more elements to get a proper solution.

Comment: Did you install any software lately? Have you scanned for malware?

Comment: I have no malware (McAfee weekly scan) and I really can't figure out the exact moment this behaviour started... So I can't tell exactly about the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the answer. It was Ati Catalyst's Desktop Manager: I disabled "Preserve Application Position and Size" in it and my popups now are ok.

Answer (score 0):

An old registry hack for XP to force this behavior was to add a registry DWORD

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer

DWORD= maximizeapps

set value to 1

Maybe this was added somehow?

.

You can use Microsoft System Restore, pick a date before this problem began

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11238/using-system-restore-to-recover-your-windows-7-computer/

.

Comment: I tried but the key was not present. I added with value = 0 but didn't help.

Comment: Did you scan for malware?

Comment: Yes, I have McAfee in continous protection and weekly scanning and no threat.

Comment: Try the System Restore

Comment: I really can't say when the problem started, so I can't choose a date for System Restore... I don't even know if I could go back enough.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem in my case! muchas grachias!